# Question was marked as duplicate, duplicate question was asked 9 years ago, I think the question should be reopened

Tags: discussion

Question: [C++ is it possible to use macros to have a class function print from where it is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156441/c-is-it-possible-to-use-macros-to-have-a-class-function-print-from-where-it-is)

Duplicate: [print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c)

Given the speed at which technology evolves, I do not think that just because the question was already asked 9 years ago there's enough justification to mark it as a duplicate, for one, there is no mention of:
 `std::experimental::source_location` in the original question.

Comment: Accoding to the docs, `std::experimental::source_location` behaves exactly similar to `__LINE__` and `__LINE__`. That's not what you need and is not mentioned in the duplicate because it wouldn't help. Even if there would be a new approach to your problem, it should still be added as a new answer to the original post to keep all the information in one place.

Comment: The proposed duplicate target can hold new answers, potentially with that new information.

Comment: If something has changed in the past 9 years to make that solution not usable for you then *explain why the proposed solutions don't work* and that can be addressed (either with a different duplicate, or reopening the question if there isn't a solution that currently works).

Comment: As @Servy pointed out there is standard process of re-opening duplicates - the edit you've made does not in any way explain *why* answers in linked duplicate do not apply ("question already asked 10 years ago" is not a reason). It is good idea to *link* to the duplicate question in the edit as if question is re-opened none will be able to see the link (without digging through history). Also editing in an answer into the question (from "You might be interested in the proposed std::experimental::source_location" comment) is not appropriate edit.

Answer (score 8):

> Given the speed at which technology evolves, I do not think that just because the question was already asked 9 years ago there's enough justification to mark it as a duplicate

That is essentially irrelevant. If they are duplicates, then they're still duplicates. If technology has evolved in a way to change the answer, then the correct solution is to provide an answer on the target question.

*That having been said*, these questions are not duplicates. The old question is asking for a method to print the call stack. The new question is asking about a specific implementation of a tool that would result in printing a call stack.

It's the difference between asking for "How do I sort an array" and "How do I swap two items in the array so that I can sort it". They're not the same question, since the answer to the former question (call `std::sort`) won't actually tell you anything about how to properly swap items.